# Important ask about authentication

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

could you tell me if when somebody is on my application on Facebook, then I can know what ID number this user has or what email this user uses to login on Facebook? It is important for me, because i would like to know if i can authorize my apps user without oAuth2.0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the permission befoer you get the id / email.
As of today, if you don't want to use OAuth 2.0, simply handle that via the legacy authentication flow